# Shared mailbox smtp testing - exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

Is it possible to test mailboxes internally on exchange 2007, without setting up an outlook client.

I've setup 5 shared mailboxes with a new trusted domain, but have no access to an outlook client, and want to test I can send and receive emails on the new addresses and mailboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.  Do you have access to any client?  If you enable IMAP, you can test send/receive via Thunderbird IMAP and use SMTP receivers for submission.  Or use OWA.

If you're look for a programatic way to do this with no client, you can use openssl/telnet to test IMAP/SMTPS(TLS) the same way Thunderbird would but via CLI.

For IMAP: https://delog.wordpress.com/2011/05/10/access-imap-server-from-the-command-line-using-openssl/

For SMTP:  https://scottlinux.com/2014/06/05/check-for-smtp-tls-from-command-line-with-openssl/

If you're trying to test EWS/RCP-HTTP/MAPI, that's a different story.  However, if the mailboxes work with base IMAP/SMTP protocols, you know they'll work with the more involved protocols.  If the mailboxes are intended to be accessed from the outside, you can test their connectivity via: https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

Else, what are the restrictions of the testing?